# Nuxt2 CompositionAPI - Can't display imported render function on component - "template or render function not defined"

Tags: typescript, import, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

So I've made a render function that is, as far as I am aware, valid. (Fig. 1)(Fig. 2)
I'm importing this into a component and registering it within the defineComponent.

Yet, during runtime, I get a "template or render function not defined" error thrown (Fig. 3)
I believe that my import of the render function is correct and the path is valid (Fig. 4)

Could someone let me know what I am missing?

Thanks!

[image: Fig. 1]
Fig. 1

[image: Fig. 2]
Fig. 2

[image: Fig. 3]
Fig. 3

[image: Fig. 4]
Fig. 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking with a co-worker I've found the answer to my issue... (Fig. 5)

The render function needs to return a function that then calls the 'h' / 'createElement' function. Without nesting your function a basic Vue Proxy is returned instead. This doesn't get displayed on the page and causes the above issue.

Thanks for the help everyone!

[image: Fig. 5]
Fig. 5